# A standalone compiler for CoffeeScript?

Tags: coffeescript

I'm writing a simple game engine that's based on CoffeeScript and I've been wondering if there's a standalone version of the compiler, so that the user wouldn't have to install both Node.JS and CoffeeScript.

Comment: What do you mean by *standalone compiler*? If you `npm install -g coffee-script` you have a standalone compiler. Alternatively, simply pre-compile your coffee before publishing.

Comment: Oh, you mean a coffee compiler that can run without Node.js? Nope, ain't gonna happen. But as I said, simply pre-compile the coffee script to standard JavaScript before publishing and be done with it.

Comment: Well, it's supposed to compile at the end user's machine, so I pretty much can't

Comment: Well if the end product is going to be a binary (or some sort), you can always bundle your own version of Node.js with it and ensure it is called instead of the usually-globally installed version...

Comment: Hm... That could work, there would be no licensing problems, right? (The end product is going to be free)

Comment: Not sure about licensing - better check the license with your laywer! :)

Comment: Ah, thanks anyways. Can you post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, as you say, the end product is expected to be a fully functional software package, you can always include whatever external dependencies you need directly in that product - like a package.

This is actually a standard for OS X and apps downloaded from App Store (mainly) - each downloaded app contains its own binary, but it may contain other required binaries as well. Games are also frequently architected this way (the obvious deviations being DirectX and .net runtimes which need to be installed directly into the system).

Alternatively, if the target platform is Windows, you could probably package the Node.js installer together with your own installer.